# Fastest iteration over df until reach condition

Tags: python, pandas

```
            A       B
0        0.00  514.51
1        0.75  514.51
2        1.10  514.42
3        3.52  514.41
4        5.59  514.43
5        6.52  514.43
6        7.45  514.42
7        5.53  514.42
8        4.53  514.36
9        3.61  514.38
10       1.55  514.36
```

I want to select all rows, until first `A value` is greater tan 6.

Output should be:

```
            A       B
0        0.00  514.51
1        0.75  514.51
2        1.10  514.42
3        3.52  514.41
4        5.59  514.43
```

Which would be the fastest iteration mode?

I've tried:

```
def first(g):
    if g.A.ge(45.0).any():
        return g[cond].iloc[0]

df.apply(first)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `loc` with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for select all rows to first `True` by boolean mask:

```
df = df.loc[:df.A.ge(4.50).idxmax()]
print (df)
      A       B
0  0.00  514.51
1  0.75  514.51
2  1.10  514.42
3  3.52  514.41
4  5.59  514.43
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.A.ge(4.50))
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10    False
Name: A, dtype: bool

print (df.A.ge(4.50).idxmax())
4
```

There is a lot of nice solutions, so I was curious about timings:

It really depends of position of first value, so I set first value in half of index valus (in real data it should be different):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(10000)})
df.loc[5000, 'A'] = 10
#print (df)

In [66]: %timeit df[df.A.lt(6).cumprod().astype(bool)]
831 µs ± 31.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [67]: %timeit df.loc[:df.A.ge(4.50).idxmax()]
502 µs ± 4.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [68]: %timeit df.iloc[:next(idx for idx in df.index if df.iloc[idx, 0] > 6)]
67.7 ms ± 1.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [69]: %%timeit
    ...: result = df
    ...: for i, a in enumerate(df['A']):
    ...:     if a >= 6:
    ...:         result = df.iloc[:i+1,:]
    ...:         break
    ...: 
845 µs ± 8.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `cumprod`

```
df[df.A.lt(6).cumprod().astype(bool)]
Out[303]: 
      A       B
0  0.00  514.51
1  0.75  514.51
2  1.10  514.42
3  3.52  514.41
4  5.59  514.43
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `iloc` and `next`

```
df.iloc[:next(idx for idx in df.index if df.iloc[idx, 0] > 6)]
```

Following on @jezrael comments on timings, here's a graph on timings where

```
Method1 : df.iloc[:next(idx for idx in df.index if df.iloc[idx, 0] > 6)]
Method2 : df[df.A.lt(6).cumprod().astype(bool)]
Method3 : df.loc[:df.A.ge(4.50).idxmax()]
```

Such that

[image: times]

Basically M2 and M3 are very close to each other, with a slight preference for M2 as df grows beyond 100k rows+. M1 is by far the least performant for big dfs, though is faster in very small dfs.

Basically the speed depends on: where the first occurrence is, and how big is the `df`. Here I have set a fixed first occurrence near the beginning, would be interesting to see in different positions :) I may add later

Comment: Nice graph indeed -- must have taken a while to run! Would you mind testing this answer too? `df.iloc[:(df.A >= 6).nonzero()[0][0],:]`

Answer (score 0):

**Update: revised with faster answer**

For short dataframes or if the answer is early in the dataframe, you can get quick results with a Python `for` loop that iterates to the first match and then breaks (see `for_loop()` function below). But if you need to scan hundreds or thousands of rows to find a match, then it's probably faster to use vectorized functions, even if they do one or two evaluations across the whole length of the dataframe.

Others suggested some good vectorized operations, but the `nonzero()` function I added below looks like the fastest so far.

Some functions that will do the job:

```
def nonzero():
    # one-liner if you know there are matches:
    # df.iloc[:(df.A >= 6).nonzero()[0][0],:]
    indexes = (df.A.values >= 6).nonzero()[0]
    if len(indexes) > 0:
        return df.iloc[:indexes[0],:]
    else:
        return df

def for_loop():
    result = df
    for i, a in enumerate(df['A']):
        if a >= 6:
            result = df.iloc[:i,:]
            break
    return result

def idxmax():
    return df.loc[:df.A.ge(4.50).idxmax()]

def cumprod():
    return df[df.A.lt(6).cumprod().astype(bool)]

def next_idx():
    return df.iloc[:next(idx for idx in df.index if df.iloc[idx, 0] > 6)]

def test_it(func, reps):
    dur = timeit.timeit(stmt=func+'()', setup='from __main__ import df, '+func, number=reps)
    print('{}: {}'.format(func, dur))
```

Tests with small dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    [0.00, 514.51],
    [0.75, 514.51],
    [1.10, 514.42],
    [3.52, 514.41],
    [5.59, 514.43],
    [6.52, 514.43],
    [7.45, 514.42],
    [5.53, 514.42],
    [4.53, 514.36],
    [3.61, 514.38],
    [1.55, 514.36]
], columns = ['A','B'])

for func in ['nonzero', 'for_loop', 'idxmax', 'cumprod', 'next_idx']:
    test_it(func, 10000)

# nonzero: 1.28068804741
# for_loop: 1.22211813927
# idxmax: 3.8852930069
# cumprod: 6.28086519241
# next_idx: 1.78734588623
```

Here's a test with a bigger dataframe, where the first match is row 600,000 out of 1,000,000. I left out `for_loop` and `next_idx` because they take over a minute for this test.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.np.arange(0,10,0.000001), 'B':514.51})

for func in ['nonzero', 'idxmax', 'cumprod']:
    test_it(func, 100)

# nonzero: 3.25263190269
# idxmax: 9.08449816704
# cumprod: 24.7965559959
```

So it looks like a Python `for` loop with short-circuit capability can be fastest for small dataframes, but for large dataframes it's faster to test every row via a vectorized operation and then find the offset of matching rows (e.g., via the `nonzero()` function).

Comment: Do you forget for my solution? Is possible add `df.loc[:df.A.ge(4.50).idxmax()]` ?

Comment: @jezrael I just added it!

Comment: Thank you, so if small dataframe better is your solution.